# Can ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API be attacked by directory traversal?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Our security team asked me to "add logic to detect directory traversal attack" for our ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API. So I read the content from:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack
- https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal

But it seems there's no way to give it a directory traversal attack at all - the invalid URLs are not routed to the controller/actions. So, my questions are -

1. Do we need to worry about directory traversal attack?
2. If yes, what is the best way to implement?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

The Path Traversal may be a threat, but not necessarily from the `.Net Core WebAPI`, of course, it will depend on many factors:

1. How did you configure the web server. Do you allow browsing the application or any path in the server?
2. Do you allow user data (like file paths to any storage) to be specified in the incoming data?
3. Do you configure `app.UseStaticFiles()` allowing the WebAPI user specify the route, or not making sure running process only has access to that directory not apply any `../` path?
4. If you load files to your API... Do you generate a file name for the storage or use the same file name provided?

Those and many other questions may arise depending on how you configure the application/server or how you control the access or sanitize your data.

Just some food for thoughts. :)